# Is it possible to equalize a Button with a character?

Tags: java, button, character, jbutton, equals

I need help with some stuff!

```
for(z = 1; z <  19; z++)
    {            
        buttonArray[z] = new JButton(" ");
        grid.add(buttonArray[z]);
        buttonArray[z].setActionCommand("" + z);
        buttonArray[z].addActionListener(this);
    }
buttonArray[4].setText(Character.toString('X'));

if(buttonArray[4].equals('X') // problem?
{
 buttonArray[4].setText(Character.toString('O'));;
}
```

As you can see I have part of my code here. When I start my "program" it displays a window with different buttons  and it's not exactly like this (just for show the problem) but when I click on a button if there is an X I want it to "flip" and the O to appear.

I suppose the problem is in line 10 because a button can't be equal to a character. I don't really know so please could you help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the text value from the button and compare it.

```
buttonArray[4].getText().charAt(0) == 'X'
```

or

```
buttonArray[4].getText().equals(Character.toString('X'))
```

You are comparing a button object to a string.

Comment: Thanks!! Not only because your answer helped me but also because you were really fast!!

Comment: Make sure to understand what the code is doing. If you have any problems, leave a comment here. Good luck!